# Pyspark - How to apply a function only to a subset of columns in a DataFrame?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I wanted to apply a function to some columns of a `Spark` DataFrame with different methods: `fn` and a `fn1`. Here is how I did that:

```
def fn(column):
    return(x*2)

udf_1 = udf(fn, DecimalType())

def fn1(column):
    return(x*3)

udf_2 = udf(fn1, DecimalType())
    
def process_df1(df, col_name):
    df1 = df.withColumn(col_name, udf_1(col_name))
    return df1

def process_df2(df, col_name):
    df2 = df.withColumn(col_name, udf_2(col_name))
    return df2
```

For a single column it works fine. But now I get a `list` of `dict`s containing information on various columns:

```
cols_info = [{'col_name': 'metric_1', 'process': 'True', 'method':'simple'}, {'col_name': 'metric_2', 'process': 'False', 'method':'hash'}]
```

How should I parse the `cols_info` list and apply the above logic only to the columns that have `process:True` and use a required `method`?

The first thing that comes to mind is to filter out columns with `process:False`

```
list(filter(lambda col_info: col_info['process'] == 'True', cols_info))
```

But I'm still missing a more generic approach here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

selectExpr function will be useful here

```
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
from pyspark.sql.window import Window
#Test data
tst = sqlContext.createDataFrame([(1,2,3,4),(1,3,4,1),(1,4,5,5),(1,6,7,8),(2,1,9,2),(2,2,9,9)],schema=['col1','col2','col3','col4'])    

def fn(x):
    return(x*2)

def fn1(x):
    return(x*3)

sqlContext.udf.register("fn1", fn)
sqlContext.udf.register("fn2", fn1)

cols_info =[{'col_name':'col1','encrypt':False,},{'col_name':'col2','encrypt':True,'method':'fn1'},{'col_name':'col3','encrypt':True,'method':'fn2'}]
# determine which columns have any of the encryption
modified_columns = [x['col_name'] for x in cols_info if x['encrypt']]
# select which colulmns have to be retained
columns_retain = list(set(tst.columns)-set(modified_columns))
#%
expr =columns_retain+[((x['method'])+'('+(x['col_name'])+') as '+ x['col_name']) for x in cols_info if x['encrypt']]
#%
tst_res = tst.selectExpr(*expr)
```

The results will be :

```
+----+----+----+----+
|col4|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+----+
|   4|   1|   4|   9|
|   1|   1|   6|  12|
|   5|   1|   8|  15|
|   8|   1|  12|  21|
|   2|   2|   2|  27|
|   9|   2|   4|  27|
+----+----+----+----+
```

Comment: thank you. But how do I use withColumn to the whole DF, applying the functions to the specific columns after that?

Comment: Or select all the columns of a DF including modified columns with the original names?

Comment: you mean, you want to merge these columns to the whole dataframe? Here you dont need a withColumn, you can add the existing columns in the expr function. see my edited answer and let me know if it works

Comment: Yes, I need to keep the whole DF and the columns should keep their original names(col2, col3), containing the modified values. Without keeping the old values

Comment: you mean, you have to rename the calculated columns to existing columns? then you can include the as statement in your expr like this : expr =[((x['method'])+'('+(x['col_name'])+') as '+ x['col_name']) for x in cols_info if x['encrypt']]. Note that we are not incuding the tst.columns in our expr here.

Comment: I need to replace the existing columns with calculated columns as a part of the whole DF )

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/217066/discussion-between-raghu-and-samba).

Comment: can you check now?